# How to filter out this bot / prevent this "attack"?

Tags: php, symfony, web-crawler, user-agent, bots

In my symfony2 application, I made a mistake a few days ago, and in one specific page, a non-connected user could post any data in a form without any validation.

This has now been solved after I got more than 500 entries of unrelevant content in less than 1 hour.

Now, even though the malware can't post anymore, it's still visiting this only page, once every minute. I have a viewcount on this same page which then inflates anormally.

I've tried to filter out bots but it seems this one is smart. My code :

```
public function increaseViewCount(ViewCountInterface $entity, $andFlush = true)
{
    $detector = $this->get('vipx_bot_detect.detector');
    $id = 'viewcount' . get_class($entity) . $entity->getId();

    if
    (
        (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || !preg_match('~(bot|crawl|slurp|spider)~i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
        && strstr($this->get('request')->headers->get('referer'), 'foodmeup')
        && $detector->detectFromRequest($this->container->get('request')) === null
        && $this->get('session')->get($id) == false
    )
    {
        $entity->increaseCount();
        $this->persist($entity);
        if ($andFlush) $this->flush($entity);
        $this->get('journal_manager')->addJournalEntry('view', array(
                'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
                'REMOTE_ADDR' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                'time' => time(),
                'date' => date("d/m/Y H:i:s"),
                'referer' => $this->get('request')->headers->get('referer')
            ), $entity->getId(), get_class($entity));
        $this->get('session')->set($id, true);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

However (as you can see I logged the entry) the result i get is the following : the user agent does not contain any bot name.

```
Paramètre   Valeur
HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 YaBrowser/14.10.2062.12521 Safari/537.36
REMOTE_ADDR 91.200.12.7
time    1430510089
date    01/05/2015 21:54:49
referer mywebsite/permettre-de-suggerer-une-photo-sur-les-elements-qui-n-en-ont-pas
```

So I have its IP and I figured out the last 100 visits of the last hour all came from somewhere in Ukrania.

Still, when I check my googleAnalytics account, there is no trace of these visits.

- So how can I resolve this issue ?

  - Is implementing a javascript viewcount the safest way to go ?
  - I've not yet set a bot trap but here the IP changes everytime so I'm not sure it would work in that case.
  - Which other data can I retrieve to understand better how to solve this ?

Comment: Is this bot the only instance in your logs of that user agent? If so, just block by UA - with all those version numbers, it is unlikely to be used by someone else. [This is also of interest](https://www.webmasterworld.com/search_engine_spiders/4628525.htm).

Comment: well, indeed, that UA is used in eastern europe. I don't see a reason for one of my targets to have it so i'll block YaBrowser, thanks !

Comment: No probs. I wonder if GA doesn't register the hits as it requires JavaScript, but the bot is cURL-based and has no JS engine.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Deny in your Apache configuration - this might do:

```
Deny from 91.0.0.0/8
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html#host

Use this with care - because it will block all requests from that IP CIDR block.  http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-91-0-0-0-1/pft

Comment: unfortunately, the IP is different for every log entry, this won't work here... I guess those are zombie computers

Comment: This will block all requests from the entire CIDR block - do all the requests originate from IP addresses that start with 91?

Comment: they all do start with 91. what is a CIDR block? is that the meaning of the /8 at the end?

Comment: A CIDR block lets you identify a group of IP addresses.  I chose 91.0.0.0/8 by using the whois link to find all the IP addresses in the block with the IP address you referenced.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Answer (score 0):

The only proper way is to sanitize all inputs server-side, like you eventually did. Blocking a /8 IP range is so callous I can't even start to describe how much of a malpractice that is. 
If I were to suggest a truly redundant way of securing this, it would be a reverse proxy server. This would do some rudimentary browsing pattern analysis and unlock the posting for a user who loaded the files in an expected way. If more advanced, it could also randomize the POST field names that your server expects, but I suppose that would be gilding the lily at this point.